# python chess board.attackers how to use

Tags: python, python-chess

I'm playing around with some python chess code, its for fun.
However i have difficulty in using the board.attackers function.
I'm not sure what it accepts
This code below makes use of the chess lib described here:
http://python-chess.readthedocs.io/en/latest/core.html

in the docs example code exists where they put in chess.F3
though i need some conversion from move to chess.xx i guess ?.

```
def staticAnalysis(board, move, my_color):
  score = random.random()
  board.push(move)
 
  for (piece, value) in [(chess.PAWN, 1), 
                       (chess.BISHOP, 4), 
                       (chess.KING, 0), 
                       (chess.QUEEN, 10), 
                       (chess.KNIGHT, 5),
                       (chess.ROOK, 3)]:
    score += len(board.pieces(piece, my_color)) * value
    score -= len(board.pieces(piece, not my_color)) * value
     
  score += 100 if board.is_checkmate() else 0
  score += 10 if board.is_capture(move)  else 0

  # to get proposed destination of the move, removes piece, thus Ph1 becomes h1
  square =  str(move)[-2:]  

  # but its not accepted ?.. what can be used to do achieve this ?.
  myAttackers = board.attackers(not my_color,  square)
  score +=len(attackers)*-2

return score
```

Comment: where is `attackers` defined?

Comment: attacker is a new variable for the board.attacker as in the manual https://python-chess.readthedocs.io/en/latest/core.html? I think the problem is in my square its not the proper input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are built-in methods that take care of converting between a square's `str` name and `int` value already:

```
>>> chess.square_name(21)
'f3'
>>> chess.parse_square('f3')
21
```

However, [your solution using `ord()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74063024/7304977) is technically more efficient as it runs in O(1) whereas `chess.parse_square` calls `SQUARES.index(...)` and runs in O(n). But no need to reinvent the wheel here.

---

For more context, `chess.Square` is simply an alias for a Python `int`. Here is the [actual source code](https://github.com/niklasf/python-chess/blob/master/chess/__init__.py#L180-L190) where it's defined:

```py
Square = int
SQUARES = [
    A1, B1, C1, D1, E1, F1, G1, H1,
    A2, B2, C2, D2, E2, F2, G2, H2,
    A3, B3, C3, D3, E3, F3, G3, H3,
    A4, B4, C4, D4, E4, F4, G4, H4,
    A5, B5, C5, D5, E5, F5, G5, H5,
    A6, B6, C6, D6, E6, F6, G6, H6,
    A7, B7, C7, D7, E7, F7, G7, H7,
    A8, B8, C8, D8, E8, F8, G8, H8,
] = range(64)
```

This is shorthand for `chess.A1`=`0`, `chess.B1`=`1`, ... , `chess.H8`=`63`.

In your code, you are providing `attackers()` with a string (because you define `square = str(move)[-2:]` ), not a `chess.Square` (an `int`), which is causing your error.

You can replace the line where you define `square` with this, so its type is actually `chess.Square` (here I know the type of `move` is `chess.Move` since you use `board.push(move)` earlier):

```py
square = move.to_square  # a ``chess.Square``
```

---

On a side note, I noticed your piece values look a bit off. Maybe you wanted them like this:

```py
[(chess.PAWN, 1),
(chess.BISHOP, 3),
(chess.KING, 0),
(chess.QUEEN, 9),
(chess.KNIGHT, 3),
(chess.ROOK, 5)]
```

Comment: values of knight and bishop, are well complex to say at least.
Especially towards end games, I prefer knights above bishops, and if one has only one bishop left it depends on pawn position (blocking /defending). Most people in my chess club though agree a knight is slightly higher, although left with 2 bishops for an end game is a different story.

Comment: @Peter Above are just the widely-accepted values ([ex1](https://www.chess.com/terms/chess-piece-value), [ex2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_piece_relative_value)). Some places I've heard call a knight 3 and a bishop 3.25, with other heuristics in place ex. if it's an open endgame with BB vs. NN—but it's futile to use human reasoning to beat the computer-verified values. At least a rook should certainly not be 3 if a bishop is 5. At least my opinion as a 2000-rated on lichess.

Comment: it's not only human reasoning, its common knowledge, but most engines dont go that deep into this matter.

Answer (score 0):

For us to have a better idea, you should define your functions and variables. A bit of googling found the docs here: https://python-chess.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Based on this snippet in the docs `attackers = board.attackers(chess.WHITE, chess.F3)`, it looks like you need to pass the color and square not as a string but as the `chess.` function.

Comment: I red that but how to convert a proposed move as in the function(board, move, my color) into the format chess.F3, ..its a different format. ( i tried square function to get the final position but its not compatible with ches.xx

Answer (score 0):

Ok its more simple then i thought..

```
print(chess.B2)
#equals
print ((ord("B")-ord("A"))+(2-1)*8)
```